# Controlling the Speed of the Car

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been trying to control the speed of the car in Unity4. I am providing the code details below. Do I need to upgrade the code? As because when the brake(space bar) is pressed the Speed is set to Zero but when the brake is released the Speed is increasing again.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CarMovementScript : MonoBehaviour
{


    public Vector3 com;
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public WheelCollider FrontLeft;
    public WheelCollider FrontRight;
    public WheelCollider RearRight;
    public WheelCollider RearLeft;
    public float maxspeed = 40;
    public float carspeed = 0;
    public float speed = 0.0f;
    float braking = 75.0f;
    float turning = 30.0f;

    void Start()
    {

        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        rb.centerOfMass = new Vector3(rb.centerOfMass.x, -0.9f, rb.centerOfMass.z);
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if (speed <= maxspeed)
        {
            Debug.Log(speed);
            //this code makes car go forward
            RearRight.motorTorque = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed;
            RearLeft.motorTorque = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed;
            speed += 0.05f;
        }



        //this code works for braking of the car
        RearRight.brakeTorque = 0;
        RearLeft.brakeTorque = 0;

        //this code is for turning
        FrontRight.steerAngle = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * turning;
        FrontLeft.steerAngle = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * turning;


        //Breaking
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            RearRight.brakeTorque = braking;
            RearLeft.brakeTorque = braking;
            speed = 0.0f;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before actually posting a question. The page consists of rules and lots of useful hints to post questions, which actually get an (good) answer. For code-reviews, have a look at [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your statement:

```
when the brake is released the Speed is increasing again.
```

My guess is that your this piece of code needs attention:

```
    if (speed <= maxspeed)
    {
        Debug.Log(speed);
        //this code makes car go forward
        RearRight.motorTorque = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed;
        RearLeft.motorTorque = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed;
        speed += 0.05f;
    }
```

When you apply break, the speed goes to zero, but since `speed <= maxspeed` so it returns true and car starts moving due to `speed += 0.05f`. So you should probably block this condition unless there is an input for vertical axis. Like: (untested, to give you an idea)

```
    float vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    if ((speed != 0 && speed <= maxspeed) || 
        (speed == 0.0 && vertical > 0.0))
    {
        Debug.Log(speed);
        //this code makes car go forward
        RearRight.motorTorque = vertical * speed;
        RearLeft.motorTorque = vertical * speed;
        speed += 0.05f;
    }
```

This way, if condition will execute iff either *brake applied and from vertical axis there is a gain in speed*  or *there is already a gain in speed and speed is limited with maxspeed*

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

don't set speed to 0 instead decrement it by 0.05f.

remove this

```
if (speed <= maxspeed)
{
    Debug.Log(speed);
    //this code makes car go forward
    RearRight.motorTorque = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed;
    RearLeft.motorTorque = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed;
    speed += 0.05f;
}
```

and change

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
{
    RearRight.brakeTorque = braking;
    RearLeft.brakeTorque = braking;
    speed = 0.0f;

}
```

to

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
{
    RearRight.brakeTorque = braking;
    RearLeft.brakeTorque = braking;
    speed -= 0.05f;

}
else if (speed <= maxspeed)
{
   Debug.Log(speed);
   //this code makes car go forward
   RearRight.motorTorque = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed;
   RearLeft.motorTorque = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed;
   speed += 0.05f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code for turning. But the turning gets multiplied automatically at the beginning. What Code changes must be done to adjust the turning? 
FrontRight.steerAngle = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * turning;
        FrontLeft.steerAngle = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * turning;

Comment: Please instead of adding it as an answer either update your question or post  a new question

Answer (score 0):

paste this in update function/method.

```
void Update()
    {
        //20.0f is maxSpeed
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity, 20.0f);
    }
```